# Speed of breaking (guitar) string

Tags: speed, string

As I was playing the guitar yesterday, one of the strings broke and injured one of my fingers lightly.

Astonished by the power of a breaking string, I was wondering whether there is a way to calculate the maximum speed of a snapping string given its tension (e.g. $F_T = 10kg * 9.8ms^{-2} = 98N$ in case of the high e-string).

Comment: There is, roughly.  You know the total force (tension), so to first approximation pretend the string is massless with a point mass equal to the mass of the string placed at the location of the break. Then you can calculate the terminal velocity.  To solve the problem exactly, you need to integrate the local tension & mass along the length of the string.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about doing exactly that, altough I wasn't sure whether I could simply approximate the problem by assuming the string was a single mass point.
So you suggest that I assume the tension (over time) is constant and doesn't decay (like it would in reality)?

Comment: THE MECHANICS OF HIGHLY-EXTENSIBLE CABLES [abstract: "For a breaking cable we find that the speed of snapback, which can have potentially catastrophic effects"](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022460X98915267) This seems to be a free download: [The dynamics of highly extensible cables](http://dspace.mit.edu/handle/1721.1/10730)